# sms sending in php by passing variables in url by using curl

Tags: php, curl

Hi i need to send sms by using php. I am using curl method to post variables in url but i cant get sms. I can get result by using get method, is there any problem in my code?

```
$url = 'http://online.chennaisms.com/api/mt/SendSMS?';
$postData = array();
$postData['user'] = 'abc';
$postData['password'] = 'qwftgry ';
$postData['senderid'] ='reyty';
$postData['channel'] ='Trans';
$postData['DCS'] =0;
$postData['flashsms'] =0;
$postData['number'] = 91XXXXXXXXXX;
$postData['text'] ='hai ';
$postData['route'] =28;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: the spaces at the end of the password might not help much, or putting a telephone number as a very long number, instead of a 'string' of digits.

Comment: i given correctly in my code , here i just given for rough phone number

Comment: Try using the curl_error() and curl_errno() functions to check for errors.

Comment: @Ray O'Donnel , thanks for your idea, i tried as you say ,  i am grtting no error in curl

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete **?** character at the end of url

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference - it's a valid URL with or without the "?".

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your code, apart from the lack of any error-checking on the cURL transaction (by means of `curl_error()` etc), so you should probably look elsewhere - was an error message returned by the SMS provider, for example?

Comment: Aha - so does the provider expect GET requests instead of POST?

Comment: but how can i give variables in get method?

Comment: You'll have to read the docs for your provider's API - it will depend completely on how that is defined.